# React Native Error : undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.flatList = flatList')

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, react-native-flatlist

I made a carousel of images and now when I try to open the first screen where it contained the carousel, it gives me the error "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.flatList = flatList')". At first my  error was "Animated.event now requires a second argument for options", which I resolved it using {useNativeDriver: true} ( I got it from here (https://github.com/nysamnang/react-native-raw-bottom-sheet/issues/81)), but now its giving me the error that 'this.flatList = flatList is undefined.....

any ideas on what could be the reason??

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions, FlatList, Animated } from 'react-native'
import CarouselItem from './CarouselItem'
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window')





const Carousel = ({ data }) => {
const scrollX = new Animated.Value(0)
let position = Animated.divide(scrollX, width)





if (data && data.length) {
    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList data={data}
            ref = {(flatList) => {this.flatList = flatList}}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key' + index}
                horizontal
                pagingEnabled
                scrollEnabled
                snapToAlignment="center"
                scrollEventThrottle={16}
                decelerationRate={"fast"}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return <CarouselItem item={item} />
                }}
onScroll={Animated.event(
[{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }
{useNativeDriver:true},
                )}
            />

            <View style={styles.dotView}>
                {data.map((_, i) => {
                    let opacity = position.interpolate({
                        inputRange: [i - 1, i, i + 1],
                        outputRange: [0.3, 1, 0.3],
                        extrapolate: 'clamp'
                    })
                    return (
                        <Animated.View
                            key={i}
                            style={{ opacity, height: 10, width: 10, backgroundColor: '#27FFFF', margin: 8, borderRadius: 5 }}
                        />
                    )
                })}

            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
dotView: { flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', bottom:20,  }
})
export default Carousel
```

Thank you in advanced for helping me resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your flatlist you are trying to assign a reference to a variable called flatlist that doesn't exist:

```
<View>
    <FlatList data={data}
    -->  ref = {(flatList) => {this.flatList = flatList}}
```

To solve this issue, you have to create the variable as a reference like this.

const flatlist = React.createRef();

or using hooks:

const flatlist = React.useRef(null);

```
const Carousel = ({ data }) => {
const scrollX = new Animated.Value(0)
let position = Animated.divide(scrollX, width)

// new line
const flatlist = React.createRef();

if (data && data.length) {
    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList data={data}
```

Comment: well it didn't work for me, but when you said that I was trying to reference a variable that doesnt exist, you know I could have just removed it in the first place HAHAHHAHAHAHA, and now the issue is gone, Thanks so much!!!!